# Usage of $past in System Verilog Assertions

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I want to check if the current value of variable is '1' then the previous value of the variable should be '0'. I am using $past in System Verilog Assertions. Here I am checking if cal_frame_mode=1, then it's previous value of cal_frame_mode=0. My code is below. However, I am seeing assertion failure. When I check in the waveform it's behaving correctly. Assertion flags 2 clock after the the first check. How to stop this assertion after checking just one clock cycle?.

```
property p_NOP_2_RX_CAL;
  @(posedge clk)
  (cal_frame_mode==3'b001) |-> ##2 $past(cal_frame_mode)==3'b000;  
endproperty

assert_nop2cal : assert property(p_NOP_2_RX_CAL);
```

Answer (score 5):

`##2` means wait two clocks. The default of `$past` looks at the value of the expression one clock back from the current clock (by default this is the clock defined in the property). Therefore:

```
(cal_frame_mode==3'b001) |-> ##2 $past(cal_frame_mode)==3'b000;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(cal_frame_mode==3'b001) |-> ##1 cal_frame_mode==3'b000;
```

What you want is: `(cal_frame_mode==3'b001) |-> $past(cal_frame_mode)==3'b000;` but I'm guessing the reason you had the `##2` is to filter out `cal_frame_mode` equaling one for two clocks. If so, then the better solution is to add `$change` or `!$stable` to the antecedent, this what the check is only performed when the `cal_frame_mode` changed and the current value is one.

```
$changed(cal_frame_mode) && (cal_frame_mode==3'b001) |-> $past(cal_frame_mode)==3'b000;
```

Assertions are documented in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 16 *Assertions*
 § 16.9.3 *Sampled value functions* describes `$sample`, `$rose`, `$fell`, `$stable`, `$changed`, and `$past` in detail
 § 16.12.6 *Implication* describes `|->` and `|=>`